# Delete rule for one-to-one relationship

Tags: core-data, cascade, rule

I have 2 entities: `Department <---->> Employee`. So, the department has a one-to-many relationship with employee, and employee has a one-to-one relationship with department.

What should be the delete rule of the one-to-one relationship? If I choose cascade, I can see that the department is deleted when I delete an employee and of course I don't want that. I think the logical option for the delete rule would be "No Action", but then I get a warning. Am I missing something, or should the delete rule really be "No Action" in this scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nullify.

If you choose no action, then the employee will still be in the department's list of employees, but will be deleted. Likely a crash.

Nullify in this context means when you delete an employee, remove that employee from the inverse relationship (employees) of its department.

Comment: Thanks. Does the relationship department in the entity employee have to be optional? When I try to remove an employee, I get a crash if the department isn't optional. It works fine if it's optional, but I don't see the logic.

Comment: It sounds like you removed the employee from the department but you didn't delete the employee object. So, it depends what you intend. If you want to keep the employee object around (record of a former employee) then make the department optional. If you want to delete the employee object, then do so, and the department doesn't have to be optional I think. A deleted object doesn't have to pass validation.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your 2 answers were very useful to clarify how the delete rules work.